# What are IntelliJ IDEA sbt imported 'xxx-build' modules for?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

When importing a **multi-project** `build.sbt` from intelliJ IDEA 2016.1.2 using the native sbt import function, it prompts me which modules I would like to include. The list includes the subprojects/subdirectories in the directory structure I would expect e.g. 'aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', but then it also offers to import 'aaa-build', 'bbb-build', 'ccc-build', which I have not created.

Ignoring/deselecting the '-build' modules doesn't appear to have any adverse effects.

**Can somebody tell me what the purpose of those extra modules is?** Just curious.

The directory structure looks something like this:

```
root/bulid.sbt
root/project
root/aaa
root/aaa/build.sbt
root/aaa/src/main/scala
root/aaa/src/test/scala
root/bbb
root/bbb/build.sbt
...
```

Comment: I've also noticed that for a new project, if you right-click on the root in the 'project' tab, you'll find an option "add framework support ...". Selecting this will create a `xxx-build` directory. Don't know if this is related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A newer to scala,if something gets wrong with my answer, I'll improve it.

Those *-build ,they are project subfold in your projects,when you compile these projects with sbt, sbt will read it's peoperties and plugins from peoject fold. It's just like your config which has been compiled.

Comment: "They are project subfold" - that's not correct. I do not have any subfolders named *-build. Hence my question.

Comment: the fold's name is 'project' . you have it ?

Comment: Yes, I have a `root/project` folder. And even a `root/project/project` folder too, which looks a bit weird ... but I don't have any folders called 'build'? Perhaps I don't understand what you're saying. Can you give an example?

Comment: I see now what you were saying. The folder `root/project` becomes `root-build`. And the content of these `project` folders is explained here : https://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Organizing-Build.html